# Should I use who or whom when the subject is plural?

Tags: whom

I realise there has been a lot of discussion of who vs whom on these forums, but as far as I can tell none of the previous posts answer my question.  Which of these sentences is (more) correct, and why?

"South American footballers, including the likes of Maradona, Garrincha, and Pelé **whom** I have met, are coming to the party."

OR

"South American footballers, including the likes of Maradona, Garrincha, and Pelé **who** I have met, are coming to the party."

Please assume that the writer isn't taking the stance that who should be used all time, but instead wishes to use whom where it would be traditionally appropriate to do so.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the subject being plural.

Comment: This question is should be reopened. The question is supposedly duplicates doesn't address plurality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

‘Who’ does not inflect for number: it is always ‘who’ as the subject of a clause and ‘whom’ in all other contexts, whether its antecedent is singular or plural.

That said, your phrase is rather ambiguously worded (have you only met Pelé, or have you met all three, or have you met a lot of South American footballers, including Maradona, Garrincha, and Pelé? Or have you met *all* the South American footballers that are coming to the party). It doesn’t flow very well, and there seems to be some kind of determiner missing at the very beginning: if you remove the (I presume) parenthetical clauses, you’re left with the sentence, “South American footballers are coming to the party”, which is not incorrect, but sounds like a newspaper heading where determiners are often left out. Adding ‘many’ or ‘a lot of’ would make it sound more natural. I would suggest:

> Many South American footballers are coming to the party, including the likes of Maradona, Garrincha, and Pelé, all of whom I have met.

(Assuming of course that those three were the ones you intended to single out as having met)

Answer (score 3):

If you are taking the view that you want to use *whom* when it's correct to do so (and not simply default to *who*) then...

*Whom* does not inflect for number, just as *who* does not. *Whom* indicates that it refers to the object of the verb.

In your examples, ***whom*** is correct [as is *who*, but *whom* **does** refer to the object of *met*, so *whom* **can** be used].

However, it is slightly ambiguous because it could refer only to Pele or to all three footballers. A viable disambiguation might be

> South American footballers, including the likes of Maradona, Garrincha, and Pelé — **all of whom** I have met — are coming to the party.

[Note that *whom* in the prepositional phrase *all of whom* **cannot** be replaced by *who*.]

Comment: I assume that you say *who* is correct because it can be seen as the subject of *are coming to the party*, but the *meeting* and *coming* clauses are not parallel and are a bit ambiguous (in addition to the number ambiguity). A rephrasing seems in order.

Comment: No, I'm saying that *who* is correct because it **can** be used in place of *whom* in the examples. It's awkward, and it's not something I would do, but that wouldn't stop *who* being used in speech.

Comment: Are you suggesting that *who* is now an acceptable form as an objective case pronoun?

Comment: I'm suggesting that those of us who would rather not say that are being painted into the corner of the obsolescence of *whom* :-(