# "...will divide the people (who/whom) most need to be brought together"

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, grammatical-case, whom, who

> With a two-party system, our nation will divide the people (who/whom)
>   most need to be brought together.

Do I use *who* or *whom* for this sentence?  I think that "people" is the direct object and warrants the use of "whom", but I want to make sure I'm right.

Comment: What's the subject of the verb *need*?

Comment: The subject is "the people".  I take it the answer is "who", then.  Especially because you can substitute "who" for "they" to make the statement "they most need to be brought together".

Comment: So while the answer above is "who", introducing a new pronoun to take the action of "dividing" changes the answer to whom?

Comment: One trick to figure it out: "*They* need to be brought together" or "*them* need to be brought together"?

Comment: The rule I was taught (before it became acceptable to replace almost any "whom" with "who") is that a relative pronoun's case is determined by the relative clause that it introduces, not by the rest of the sentence. In your example, that relative clause is "who(m?) most need to be brought together." Here "who(m)" is the subject, so "who" is correct.  It doesn't matter that this relative clause modifies the direct object "people" of "divide" in the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Related: **1.** [Should I use who or whom when the subject is plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122330/should-i-use-who-or-whom-when-the-subject-is-plural) **2** [The use of nominative “whom”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181992/the-use-of-nominative-whom) **3** [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly/235024#235024)

Comment: **4** [How do I choose between ‘who’ or ‘whom’ when the subject pronoun is murky?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/how-do-i-choose-between-who-or-whom-when-the-subject-pronoun-is-murky)

Comment: Perhaps we could avoid the problem entirely by using "that":
"With a two-party system, our nation will divide the people that most need to be brought together."

Answer (score 24):

Because the subject of *who most need* is simply *who*, you have to use

> With a two-party system, our nation will divide the people **who most need** to be brought together.

If you want a *whom* example, try

> With a two-party system, our nation will divide the people **whom you** most need brought together.

The relative pronoun takes the case of the role it plays in its clause.

A simple rule of thumb is that if you can get away with omitting the relative pronoun, then it must be *whom* if you don’t omit, while if you cannot omit it and have the sentence still make any sense, then it must be either *who* or *whose*.

Comment: Isn't *whom* dead yet?

Comment: @Octopus: If  *whom* is facing certain death, I hereby promise to give it refuge in my regular speech.

Comment: @Octopus Ask not if for 'whom' the bell tolls...

Comment: @StigHemmer Never to send to know

Comment: @Octopus Isn't _who_ dead yet? \*runs away\*

Answer (score 2):

I like the he/him rule: if you rewrite the clause using he and him and see what makes sense, that tells you whether it's who or whom.  Which works better: "he needs to be brought together", or "him needs to be brought together"?  I think the former works (ignoring the difficulty of bringing together one person), therefore I think the original sentence needs "who".

Comment: You can just as well test with *they/them*. It only fails for *it*. (And using *she/her* will not distinguish *whom* from *whose*, but people usually do not have that problem.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Subject | Direct Object | Indirect object | Possessive
======================================================
he      | him           | to him          | his
they    | them          | to them         | theirs
who     | who           | to whom         | whose
```

As @tchrist pointed out, "the people who need" are the subject of the sentence, so it's *who*, not *whom*.

*Whom* is usually the **indirect object** of the sentence, as in

> "To whom should I make this cheque payable".

When you have a **direct object**, it's usually *who*, as in

> "He doesn't care who he hurts with his snarky comments".

According to [this Oxford Dictionaries blogpost](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom), whether to use *who* or *whom* for the direct object is in flux and a matter of personal preference.

Comment: So  if it's "technically incorrect," 
 you can use 'who' instead of 'whom'?

Comment: I meant that using "who" as the direct object is probably technically incorrect - but "whom" sounds odd in that sentence.

Comment: this is all much easier in German with its well-defined cases (Nominative, Accusative, Dative, and Genitive)

Comment: Why should the way something sounds override technical correctness?

Comment: depends if you are a believer in *prescriptive* grammar (telling people what to say/write), or *descriptive* grammar (describing what people actually say/write).

Comment: according to this Oxford Dictionaries blogpost, whether to use who or whom for the direct object is in flux and a matter of personal preference. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/who-or-whom

Comment: And which are you a believer in?

Comment: I fall somewhere between prescriptive and descriptive -  for dialect usage (e.g. "I was sat"), I go for descriptive; for things that are just incorrect (e.g. "I would of") I am prescriptive; and this instance, as the Oxford Dictionary blogpost suggests, also falls somewhere between the two.

Comment: I've never before heard that an indirect object is somehow less apt to conflate subject and object than is a direct object.

Comment: see the Oxford Dictionaries blogpost if you don't believe me. It's not about conflating the two; it's about whether the direct object should be "whom" or not.

Comment: My cousin and all her friends  say 'I would of been there if I'd knowed about it'? I asked her why and she said it sounds best. But you think she's wrong, and all her friends and neighbors? In fact you say "just incorrect". Are they just incorrect if they think it sounds best?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription

Comment: @Yvonne I didn't get a ping for your last comment. Anyway, no thanks. I'll take a pass on reading Wikipedia. I don't read it. Don't want to be fed incorrect, incomplete, misleading or outdated material presented in terrible English.  Do you have another reference?

Comment: @Clare They _say_ "would of"? Or they say "would've" and write "would of"?

Comment: @Clare - let me Google that for you... http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/ling001/prescription.html

Comment: This doesn't have to do with direct objects vs. indirect objects. It's a matter of "whom" being necessary in the exact phrase "to whom". It's fine to use "who" in a sentence like "They are the ones who I gave the book to".

Comment: Yes, it does. See the Oxford Dictionaries blogpost that I linked to.